# Sort Firebase results client side

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase for web and I have a problem sorting some data.

I know I can't use 2 orderBy, so i made a orderByChild and returned the data I need. Now I need to order them by date.

Tried a lot of things but nothing worked, what I tried:

First I push the data retrieved to an array then

- used object.values with .sort, no success
- used lodash with _.orderBy, empty array
- changed the syntax of both above, no success
- ordered another data not retrieved from Firebase and worked (lodash orderBy example)

Any advice?
Desired behavior:

Expected: [image]

Code I am using:

```
var ref2 = firebase.database().ref(sessionToken+'/users/agendas/');
ref2.orderByChild('animalUid').equalTo(codigoAnimal).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  var dadosFiltrados = snapshot.val();
  var keys = snapshot.key;

  var appendAulas = $('#atendimentosTimeline');
  var tdLine = "";
  tdLine += '<div class="timeline__box"><div class="timeline__date"><span class="timeline__day"></span><span class="timeline__month">'+dadosFiltrados.hora+' - '+dadosFiltrados.end+'</span></div>';

  var ref3 = firebase.database().ref(sessionToken+'/users/atendimento/');
  ref3.orderByKey().equalTo(dadosFiltrados.idAtendimento).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  // firebase.database().ref(sessionToken+'/users/atendimento/'+dadosFiltrados.idAtendimento).once("value", function(info){
  var keyAtendimento = snapshot.key;
  var dadosAtendimento = snapshot.val();
```

I need to sort the data in `dadosFiltrados`.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Added more information, sorry i am new here.

Comment: Thanks for that update. It's still hard for me to follow what the code is trying to do. If you're only asking about how to sort children retrieved with a `child_added`, then please only include information and code relevant to that in your question. A quick first note: `ref3.orderByKey().equalTo(dadosFiltrados.idAtendimento).on("child_added"` is just an inefficient way to do `ref3.child(dadosFiltrados.idAtendimento).on("value"`. I also think you want to use `once` there, since I have a feeling you only need the value once.

Comment: I just need to sort the data on child_added on ref2, the code below is to retrieve another information, sorry for adding it too. Why is inneficient? You are right, i need it once. Is there any performance benefit using this syntax? Thanks

Comment: I guess i found the problem: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-ordered-data, "Children with a value of true for the specified child key come next. If multiple children have a value of true, they are sorted lexicographically by key."

Comment: Solved the problem, thanks @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Good to hear! If you think your solution may be useful to others, post it as an answer below. Self-answering questions is totally acceptable here on Stack Overflow, and a great way to build reputation.

Comment: I made a backup of the database, changed the key to be lexicographically and imported the database again, so the orderByChild returned the results sorted.

Comment: Sounds like a valid solution, so I'd definitely post it (with code) as answer answer.

Comment: @andreescocard Post your answer *as an answer*, not as part of the question.  Keep the Q&A separate.

Comment: Thanks @Amy for the information, i am new here

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

OrderByChild comes sorted by Firebase (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-ordered-data)
So i exported the database (.json file), edited the entries using the key not lexicographically (check the keys of the retrieved data before), saved and imported.